# Background blocks in parallax doesn't work when they are full-sized

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my parralax. When I try some parralax background tutorial, it doesn't work fine in high-resolution. So I use `background-size: cover;`

Then the background occuped the whole space of my screen but there are enormous space between each background when I resize my windows in some resolution (like 4:3 resolution). And I don't know why.

I use [this tutorial](http://lory-huz.fr/parralax/) of to show you the problem. Try to resize the window and you will see these space.

Comment: Lory Huz, did my Answer solve your Question?

Comment: No sorry, If I use background-size:cover; it's mean I need it. The problem has been resolved by using the last version of the parralax script I used.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to use **`background-size: cover;`** that you added to your **`CSS`**.

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCggg/embedded/result/)

If you need to, explain why it doesn't work fine in high-resolution for you.